# How to show that $O=(-r, r)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $0<\mu(A)<\infty$. Define for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $$f(x):=\int \chi_A(x+t)\chi_A(t)dt.$$

We can know that $f(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that there exists $r>0$ so that $(-r, r)\subset A-A:=\{x-y: x, y\in A\}$.

---

My idea is as follows.

Note that
$$
f(x)=\int \chi_A(x+t)\chi_A(t)dt=\int\chi_{A-\{x\}}(t)\chi_A(t)dt=\int \chi_{A-\{x\}\cap A}(t)dt.
$$

Since $f$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}((0,\infty))$ is open. Also, $0\in f^{-1}((0,\infty))$ because $f(0)=\int \chi_A(t)dt=\mu(A)>0$.

Since
$$
\int f(x)dx=\int\int \chi_A(x+t)\chi_A(t)dtdx=\int\int \chi_A(x+t)\chi_A(t)dxdt=\mu(A)^2>0.
$$
Hence, $f^{-1}((0,\infty))$ is non-empty.

Then there is an non-empty open interval $O$ containing $0$ with $O\subset f^{-1}((0,\infty))$.

Claim: if $f(x)\neq 0$, then $x\in A-A$

Hence, $O\subset A-A$.

**Question: how to show that $O=(-r, r)$?**

Comment: $(-r ,r) \subseteq O$ for some $r>0$. You don't need equality.

Comment: Why can we find such type open interval?

Comment: $O$ is an open interval containing $0$. If $0 \in (a,b) \subseteq O$ take $r=\min \{-a, b\}$.

Comment: I think the reasoning is like this: f is continuous, $f(0)>0$, hence there is $(-r,r)$ s.t. for $x\in (-r,r), f(x)>0$, but $f(x)=m(A-\{x\}\cap A)$, so $A-\{x\}\cap A$ isn't empty, i.e. we can find $a_1,a_2 \in A$ with $a_2=a_1-x$. Hence $x=a_1-a_2 \in A-A$. It's true for any $x \in (-r, r)$, thus $(-r,r) \subset A-A$.

Comment: @Vit Do you think my proof is ok?

Comment: More or less, however I would provide more clarification for the first line and remove the double integral line b/c it's redundant. In the first line you established that $f(x)=m(A-\{x\}\cap A)$, clarify that it implies $f^{-1}((0,\infty)) \subset A-A$. Then you showed that $f^{-1}((0,\infty))$ is open and contains 0, it's enough to conclude that there is $r>0$ s.t. $(-r,r)  \subset f^{-1}((0,\infty)) \subset A-A$. You used double integration to show that $f^{-1}((0,\infty))$ isn't empty, but we already knew that $0\in f^{-1}((0,\infty))$.